# What automatic citation/bibliography programs are well-designed for law papers?

Tags: academia

I have tried Mendeley for citations and bibliography for writing law papers at my university, but it seems not to be designed for legal citations.

For example, when I want to add a Case file as an item in mendeley, and choose "case" as the item's type, it asks for "volume" rather than "case number", which causes the citation to be incorrectly formatted.

So which citation program is well-adapted to legal citations? Which program(s) should I use?

e.g. I'm using a citation style like OSCALA or Bluebook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for product recommendations are primarily opinion based.

Comment: I would say that whether a program can correctly format law citations is not opinion based.

Comment: I agree but you didn't ask "Can X format law citations and if so how do I get the intransigent thing to do it?" you asked "Find me an X that can format law citations?"

Comment: That doesn't make it opinion based though. An answer is still either correct or incorrect, hence objective and fact-based.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. It does make it too broad though.

Comment: Shopping list questions are generally _not_ on topic: see [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/260340) for more information. Having said that, perhaps [softwarerecs.se] might do what you want?